# Is it possible to get Revit sets?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I want to download those Revit models from BIM 360 , that have publish SET with some name.
For example: IFC Export.

How can I get a list of sets of the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to run a [Design Automation for Revit](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/) workitem to get that information, then decide to download them. This would require a .NET Revit plugin that checks for the SET you need.